# tsconfig: Restructure folders to turn sibling into child

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

This might be an odd question, but I have a certain file structure to distinguish between server and client files in my React application:

```
src/
  server/
      database/
          table.ts
      server.ts
      tsconfig.server.json
  util/
      math.ts
  components/
      Button.tsx
  App.tsx
  tsconfig.client.json
```

As you can see, my `server` files are nested inside of the `src` folder, which is also the root of my React application. That's not a problem, because I can simply exclude it in my client's tsconfig. However, I'd like to import the `util` folder in both my client and my server. The server's outDir (`../../server`) **should then look like this**:

```
server/
    database/
        table.js
    util/
        math.js
    server.js
```

I tried achieving this by setting the `baseUrl` and `paths` inside my `tsconfig.server.json`:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "util/*": ["../util/*"]
}
```

Which gets me **this result**, where the import within server.js leads to `util/math` and throws an Exception for not finding that obviously (while VS Code is fine with it and knows what I mean while editing the `src` files):

```
server/
    server/
        database/
            table.js
        server.js
    util/
        math.js
```

Is there a way, to turn the `util` folder, which is originally a sibling of the `server` folder into its child when compiling?

Comment: Can't you just take ```util``` out of your paths in the tsconfig and update your imports to reference them directly?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm doing for now, but that means I have to use ugly relative imports and end up with a weird file structure.